# How can I achieve this non-restrictive pseudocode style?

Tags: pseudocode

What is the best way (as in most efficient) way of writing pseudocode like below?

[image: Picture taken from Bernhard Korte, Jens Vygen - Combinatorial Optimization]

In particular I like that it is well-structured but gives enough freedom in writing (in reality it it is just standard inline text aligned in a specific way). If a library was used I would be grateful if anyone can spot if. In case there isn't such library, how can I achieve the result?

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? Which format are you using? You are more likely to get help if you post a small example which can be compiled for people to play with. If you're using LaTeX, for example, you'd start `\documentclass...` and end `\end{document}`. I suspect you're not using LaTeX, because you mention the possibility of using a 'library'.

Comment: @cfr Sorry if I wasn't accurate. I am using LaTeX, when I mentioned library I actually meant package. I haven't tried anything in particular, I have just googled some pseudocode styles and haven't found this one. I guess I can achieve it manually through, for example using `\begin{align}...` but then I would have to manually care about the line breaks, spaces and most importantly the text (which is the main part) would have to be enclosed in `\text{...}`. I want to avoid all that work if possible.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms) is a nice wiki page that explains many ways to realize algorithms (or pseudocode).

Comment: Try searching ctan for `algorithm` for example. (There's probably a topic, even, which will list a bunch of possible candidate packages.)

Comment: Have a look at the pseudo package, too, https://markov.htwsaar.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pseudo/doc/pseudo.pdf , and at https://ctan.org/topic/pseudocode in general. // You may also want to have a look at paracol, which allows you to synchronise text within columns, which may be needed to insert the left col. with numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to MS-SPO for pointing out the package `pseudo` I manged to get what I was looking for combined with `tikz` for the circled numbers. (using `mdframed` and `tabular` we can also do the boxes)

```
\pseudoset{label=\protect\circled{\arabic*},  line-height=1.2, ref}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}



\begin{mdframed}
{\hspace{0.25em} \Large Dynamic Programming Knapsack Algorithm} \\[0.5em]
\begin{tabular}{p{3em} p{30em}}
\textit{Input:}  & Nonnegative integers $n, c_1,\dots,c_n,w_1,\dots, w_n$ and $W$. \\[0.5em]
\textit{Output:} & A subset $S\subseteq \{1, \dots, n\}$ such that $\sum_{j\in S} w_j \leq W$ and $\sum_{j\in S} c_j$ is maximum.
\end{tabular} 
\end{mdframed}

\begin{pseudo}
Let $C$ be any upper bound on the value of the optimum solution, e.g. \\*& \; $C:=\sum_{j=1}^n c_j$. \\
Set $x(0,0):=0$ and $x(0,k):=\infty$ for $k=1,\dots, C$. \\
\kw{For} $j:=1$ \kw{to} $n$: \\+*&
    \kw{For} $k:=0$ \kw{to} $C$: \\+*&
        Set $s(j, k):=0$ and $x(j, k):=x(j-1, k)$ . \\-*&
    \kw{For} $k:=c_j$ \kw{to} $C$: \\+*&
        \kw{If} $x(j-1, k-c_j) + w_j \leq \min\{W, x(j,k)\}$ \kfw{then}: \\+*&
            Set $x(j,k) := x(j-1, k-c_j) + w_j$ and $s(j, k):=1$. \\---
Let $k=\max\{i\in\{0,\dots, C\}:x(n,i) < \infty\}$. Set $S:=\emptyset$. \\*&
\kw{For} $j:=n$ \kw{down to} $1$: \\+*&
    \kw{If} $s(j, k)=1$ \kw{then} set $S:= S\cup \{j\}$ and $k:=k-c_j$.
\end{pseudo}
```

[image]